# force non www to www in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have:

```
# BEGIN WithoutWWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# END WithoutWWW
```

But it won't work. I can still access both www and non www versions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

//OR
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: no, didn't work. It must be something with my server. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [R=301,L]
```