# Redirect non-www to www except subdomains by .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are a few questions like this, but my question is a little different

[Redirect non-www to www in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

[force non www to www in htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999451/force-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess)

[Redirect Non-WWW to WWW URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228653/redirect-non-www-to-www-urls)

I want to redirect the non-www version of the website to www, but it should not in any way effect the subdomains, so

```
www.example.com => www.example.com
example.com => www.example.com
sub1.example.com => sub1.example.com
sub2.example.com => sub2.example.com
```

this does not work, cause it does not behave good in case of subdomains

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This solution works fine

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

however, the important thing is I do not want to hardcode the domain name in htacess. How to (if even possible) have the above mentioned redirections for general case - without mentioned the exact domain name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.com(\.au)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: tks for the asnwer: it did not work, but maybe it is because of I have domain `example.com.au` ? is it possible to make it work both with `example.com` and `example.com.au` types of domains ?

Comment: it worked, but can we generalize the com and au part ? I mean I tried like this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[a-z]{2,3}(\.[a-z]{2})?$ [NC]`, and it worked, but is it correct syntax ? tks

Comment: Hmm your regex is not 100% foolproof to detect non-subdomains. For ex it will match `bbc.co.uk` which is a subdomain.

Comment: ok, i see, anyway this is good enough to go with, thanks for ur help and time )))